# MVC 4 ASP.NET 4.5 dynamic form builder options?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5, dynamic-forms

I have developed custom form builder type application using ASP.NET 3 years back. Now working on new project and it has similar requirement. I think there must be something new and easy to do same thing using MVC4 or ASP.NET 4.5 web forms. Any pointers?

Requirement in detail,

- This is a web application
- Authorised users login to web site and given the option to fill in the form
- This form captures the information which then sent to third party
- Third party keep reviewing their system and may ask for more details in future
- My application needs modification to capture this extra(or say changing) information

Is there any way I can change only DB model to accommodate these extra fields and they will automatically appear on form without any code changes to UI or BL level?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you are trying to accomplish but maybe this could help ?

http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/20/twitter-bootstrap-mvc4-the-template-nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc4-projects/

Look at how they automatically generate the bootstrap views depending on which view model get's passed.